How can I properly configure Nix to allow the installation of jaxlibWithCuda and other unfree packages related to CUDA?
I read this instructions to install JAX used with CUDA and use it
I copied this 3 lines :
nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" ];
hardware.opengl.enable = true;

in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
and I run this command
 sudo nixos-rebuild switch

I has taken some time and raised some warning but in the end it has said that was OK
This is my flake.nix :
{
  description = "";

  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";


  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python = pkgs.python312;


  
        python_packages = python.withPackages(ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas
          pip
          jax
          jaxlib
          jaxlibWithCuda
        ]);

        myDevTools = [
          python_packages
        ];
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;          
        };
      });
}

I can run nix develop without problem if I remove jaxlibWithCuda. But if I keep it I get this error:

   error: Package ‘cuda_cudart-12.2.140’ in /nix/store/5jgh89kgmrb687c254wxdac4cj5hqjw8-source/pkgs/development/cuda-modules/generic-builders/manifest.nix:330

has an unfree license (‘CUDA EULA’), refusing to evaluate.
   a) To temporarily allow unfree packages, you can use an environment variable
      for a single invocation of the nix tools.

        $ export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1

      Note: When using `nix shell`, `nix build`, `nix develop`, etc with a flake,
            then pass `--impure` in order to allow use of environment variables.

   b) For `nixos-rebuild` you can set
     { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true; }
   in configuration.nix to override this.

   Alternatively you can configure a predicate to allow specific packages:
     { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
         "cuda_cudart"
       ];
     }

   c) For `nix-env`, `nix-build`, `nix-shell` or any other Nix command you can add
     { allowUnfree = true; }
   to ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix.



Does this answer your question? How to allow "unfree" packages in Nix, for each situation?: {NixOS, Nix, Nix with Flakes, Nix with Flakes and Home Manager}

Flakes are hermetic -- your system configuration doesn't change how they're interpreted (very deliberately: being able to have predictable behavior was one of their main design goals). So you need to set up the nixpkgs configuration for allowUnfree within the flake.nix.
